# What happen if I return false in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I tried to return the false in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, nothing happens my app run successfully, can anyone tell why this thing work, and what's the difference (true/false) here.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc) *"Return Value
NO if the app cannot handle the URL resource or continue a user activity, otherwise return YES. The return value is ignored if the app is launched as a result of a remote notification."* - So I guess, in normal operations, nothing

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't determine if the app launches or not, just whether it can handle the "`option`" or not.

> **Return Value**
>
> `false` if the app cannot handle the `URL` resource or continue a user
>   activity, otherwise return `true`. The return value is ignored if the
>   app is launched as a result of a remote notification.
>
> <sub>Ref:
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application</sub>